# Do academic publishers advertise new publications by mailing science associations?

Tags: books, publishers

I am writing my first book proposal. Most publishers require a section on "market considerations". For example, OUP wants to know

> If the market is scholarly/professional, reference, or trade, how may it best be reached? (Direct mail, relevant journals, professional associations, libraries, book or music stores?)

I am not sure whether or not to list any relevant science associations from my (sub)discipline, which is political science, European studies in particular. Do academic publishers advertise their latest publications to these associations at all, or would it come across as unprofessional to recite them in this section?

Comment: It is publisher-specific. Give a call to the publisher before writing. As of now, this question is simply too broad.

Comment: @Leon Meier I ended up not listing associations and my proposal was accepted by a good publisher. I might write a self-answer later, so I don't think the close-vote is helpful.

Comment: Congratualtions! If you self-answer, your answer will probably be specific, while the question was broad ("do academic publishers...").